# How to do arithmetic operations in Laravel blade view?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to do subtraction operations inside the Laravel blade view. I knew it was the wrong approach I need to do it from the controller, but can someone give me the proper solution to do it directly inside the blade view?

> Note: I am a newbie to programming.

**Here is my code**

```
@if(!empty($receipt_details->total_due))
<tr>
    <th>
        Customer Old Due
    </th>
    <td>
        {{$receipt_details->all_due}} - {{$receipt_details->total_due}}
    </td>
</tr>
@endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add it at the same `{{}}` like this one

```
{{$receipt_details->all_due - $receipt_details->total_due}}
```

Comment: Error =  A non-numeric value encountered ?

Comment: Try to add each one of them in `intval` for casting

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: {{intval($receipt_details->all_due) - intval($receipt_details->total_due)}}

Comment: yes that is what i mean, if steal not work correctly check first your data

Comment: The value returns with 0 . https://ibb.co/d6zxyMz    https://ibb.co/pbgNBz3  any help?

Comment: Could you edit your question with clear info about your problem ?! or add new question with the new problem

Answer (score 0):

Optimal way for doing this will be to this in the DB query itself.

Here is the raw query sample

```
SELECT all_due, total_due, (all_due-total_due) as old_due FROM reciept_details;
```

Database engines are usually optimized to do these kinds of operations, and this will also save some resources on your application server.